# What should I do if I have misplaced my old expired passports?

Tags: passports, australia, study

I have misplaced my 2 old expired passports. I have my current passport with me. However, I need the old ones for my Australian student visa application. What should I do? My old passports expired 7 years back and I had kept them with me but now I am not able to find them anymore. I also tried to make a police report but the officer rejected it on the basis that there is no certain date of loss and they do not know where they will look for it. Also, they asked for photocopies of my old passports but I don't have a single copy of it. What should I do now?

Comment: Explain that you lost them and hope for the best.  Perhaps you can ask if a list of travels you have made will substitute, since that is what they want to see from your past passports.

Comment: @Tom Do you have any idea what would be my chances of acceptance?

Comment: It was only an idea to ask about.  I have never been in your situation so can't provide a tried and true solution.

Comment: @Tom Thanks. I will see what I can do during the process.

Comment: @MayankSharma, Instead you can tell them that while travelling from A to B via air/railways, you have misplaced it, and support it with appropriate tickets.

Comment: @onkar Oh ok. But the tickets can be recent tickets right?

Comment: yes, any genuine tickets will do, it must have proof that you have traveled on those. It can be issued as late as yesterday and as early as the day your passport expired.

Comment: @onkar Thank you. Your reply is of great help.